# Получение исходного кода функции в WinAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

На днях вопрос появился: почему, когда я в Visual Studio 2017 пытаюсь посмотреть описание какой-то функции, к примеру `VirtualAlloc`, я получаю лишь ее прототип. Кто-нибудь знает, как найти ее полный исходный код?

Хочется узнать, как оно все работает на системном уровне.

Comment: За описаниями вам надо идти на MSDN. Вот пример из Гугла для поискового запроса `msdn createwindowex`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms632680. Там и описание функции с её параметрами и возвращаемым значением, и даже нюансы применения этой функции.

Comment: Для `VirtualAlloc`: 1) [сама документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx), 2) [её перевод на русский язык](http://www.firststeps.ru/mfc/winapi/r.php?113).

Comment: @Arhad там прототип,я тебе понимаю,но я никак в упор на MSDN`е не могу это найти описание! Хочеться понимать это ,а не просто как овца знать что трава зеленая

Comment: @Arhad за русский перевод спасибо

Comment: Если вы не знаете английского, можете искать по запросу `firststeps.ru ИмяФункции`. Это, конечно, не дословный перевод, но пересказ своими словами.

Comment: @Arhad в том то и дело что там нету типичного тела функции только прототип! пример функция(прототип): void hi(int); и функци с телом: int hello() {...};

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под фразой «тело функции»? Все функции из WinAPI находятся во внешних скомпилированных библиотеках. Исходного кода у них как такового нет.

Comment: @Arhad разве? я не знал!

Comment: А как функция только с прототипо работает без тела иными словами "Исходного кода"?

Comment: ... Если конкретно — это DLL-файлы из `C:\Windows\system32`: `kernel32.dll`, `user32.dll`, `gdi32.dll`, `comdlg32.dll` и прочие.

Comment: @Arhad То есть якобы это там ихний "Исходный код"?

Comment: @fvBn исходные коды этих функций недоступны, а *.dll - это уже собранные библиотеки. Если вас интересует именно реализация (что странно), то вам придется довольствоваться ассемблерным кодом (после дизассемблера) или можно посмотреть исходники ReactOS, там много чего похоже на Windows.

Comment: Вот, нашёл хорошее объяснение работы всей этой кухни, которое шесть лет назад мне самому помогло разобраться, что к чему и как: http://bbs.vbstreets.ru/viewtopic.php?f=96&t=43712&p=6760206#p6760206.

Comment: @Алексей Саровский,да именно реализация!Мне все равно на каком языке!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ОС Windows - это коммерческая операционная система с **закрытым** исходным кодом.

Вы по-сути просите исходный код этой ОС. Легальных способов получить его нет, по крайней мере, пока Microsoft не сделает ее Open-Source.

Однако в нашем мире возможно все.

1. В сеть частенько [утекают](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2004/02/13/ms_windows_source_code_escapes/) исходные код самых разных продуктов. [Здесь](https://thepiratebay.org/torrent/3497574/Windows_2000_source_code) (ссылка на The Pirate Bay) можно найти примерно 15% исходного кода Windows 2000, возможно там есть и реализация `VirtualAlloc`.
2. Более легальный способ узнать, как работает `VirtualAlloc` (или любая другая функция WinAPI - это посмотреть исходники [ReactOS](http://www.reactos.org/).
   К примеру, в файле [virtmem.c](https://github.com/reactos/reactos/blob/c2c66aff7dacc62d125f2cd61d1167e9a2aa3fd6/dll/win32/kernel32/client/virtmem.c) можно найти исходники `VirtualAllocEx`, `VirtualAlloc`, `VirtualFreeEx` и других функций.

Comment: но если все же глубже посмотреть,то окажеться что все делает ассемблер!

Comment: @fvBn, это вы к чему?

Comment: к тому кто в kernel32.dll там находиться VirtuallAlloc() так на msdn Написано,и он наверное реализован на ассемблере или как в ReactOS на C++,вам не кажеться что большинство функций WinAPI реализованы ассемблером,или такую-же ахинею можно вытворять с памятью и на C++ как на ассемблере?

Comment: мне кажется что самая первая функция или даже строка кода при написании будь то любой Windows,начиналась с ассемблера

Comment: @fvBn, Windows написан на C, C++ и Ассемблере. "*мне кажется что самая первая функция или даже строка кода при написании будь то любой Windows,начиналась с ассемблера*" не обязательно. Думаю вам будет интересен [туториал](https://github.com/SamyPesse/How-to-Make-a-Computer-Operating-System/) по написанию своей ОС.

Comment: Можно найти исходник Windows PowerShell,он в самой виндовс обычным блокотом виден,и там на C# написано